# Can't specify Ruby 1.9.3 on Heroku cedar stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a rails app to Heroku's cedar stack.  I followed the instructions here:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions, but no luck.

My Gemfile states:

```
ruby '1.9.3'
```

But here's what is output after running:  git push heroku master

```
Counting objects: 45113, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (24245/24245), done.
Writing objects: 100% (45113/45113), 81.02 MiB | 1.44 MiB/s, done.
Total 45113 (delta 20557), reused 43737 (delta 19229)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
...
```

Comment: I know it's probably a silly question but after updating your gemfile you have done a `bundle` and the added the changed files to git (`git add .`) and re pushed to heroku?

Comment: Yes, I've done that.  Thanks.

Comment: It really really sounds like you haven't.

Comment: Thanks for making me check this again.  I was pushing the wrong branch.  Much appreciated.